# Invoking Dialog window from C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

Edit:  I am working on Web Application.

How do I invoke a Dialog window which allows us to save a file in C#?

If I am able to show the window, then I would be able to save the file automatically to the desired window

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  string saveName;
  using (SaveFileDialog saveFile = new SaveFileDialog())
  {
    if (saveFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      saveName = saveFile.FileName;
  }
```

Comment: I need System.Windows.dll  -, But i am working on Web Application. SaveFileDialog will not be supported on Web App ??

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) class in System.Windows.Forms.